# issue in facebook apps and facebook page

Tags: facebook-like

i have created one FB page, and FB app, i have include FB apps in my FB page,

but i want some code to be executed on the click event of  'Like' button,

for doing that i have added following code in my page.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        Popup.hide('modal');
        return false;
    }
);

</script>
```

but i'm getting either blank page, or sometimes it give page not available message.

do i missed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edge.create` event will not be available for "Page like", but only Like Button!

For applications running in page `signed_request` contains information about liked state of page.

If you get blank page or not available you have a problem with server-side or availability of your server, you should try to open your tab canvas outside of Facebook and ensure application settings are defined in a correct manner.